# trying to access my custom util in freemarker - Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, freemarker

I have a utility to access my custom Liferay configuration (not default Liferay), and I am able to do what I want in java code, but when it comes to freemarker I got stuck.

Here is my class that I want to access in Liferay theme freemarker Template:

class name : `CommonServicesUtil`

```
package mycompany.liferay.modules.common_services.util;

public class CommonServicesUtil {

    public static CommonServicesGroupConfiguration getCommonServicesGroupConfiguration(final long groupId) {
        try {
            return ConfigurationProviderUtil.getConfiguration(CommonServicesGroupConfiguration.class, new GroupServiceSettingsLocator(groupId, CommonServicesConstants.COMMON_SERVICES_API_BUNDLE_NAME));
        } catch (ConfigurationException ex) {
            throw new ArenaRuntimeException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }

    public static CommonServicesSystemConfiguration getCommonServicesSystemConfiguration() {
        try {
            return ConfigurationProviderUtil.getSystemConfiguration(CommonServicesSystemConfiguration.class);
        } catch (ConfigurationException ex) {
            throw new ArenaRuntimeException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

in freemarker I tried the follwoing :

```
\<#assign configuration = serviceLocator.findService("mycompany.liferay.modules.common_services.util.CommonServicesUtil")\>

\<#assign ConfigurationProvider = objectUtil("mycompany.liferay.modules.common_services.util.CommonServicesUtil")  /\>

\<#assign ConfigurationProvider = staticUtil\["mycompany.liferay.modules.common_services.util.CommonServicesUtil"\]  /\>
```

My liferay version is **7.4**

I am trying to access the configuration that I have been added to Liferay configuration

Answer (score 1):

I've always assumed that serviceLocator was for Liferay's Service Builder's classes. If you need arbitrary classes, I wouldn't know how it would find those classes on the classpath (it'll be from potentially many OSGi bundles)
At a minimum, you'd need to export the class or interface.

I'd rather recommend to implement a `TemplateContextContributor`, which makes the template so much cleaner, and don't require you to mock around with identifying specific implementation objects.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good way to get what you want by using Template-Context-Contributor
Please have a look on [liferay website](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029006112-Template-Context-Contributor)

there is a sample for that [here](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/7.0/gradle/themes/template-context-contributor)

Create a new module by running blade command for Template-Context-Contributor or use maven check liferay website , then you will end up with a new module has the following class :

```
 package com.liferay.blade.samples.theme.contributor;

 import com.liferay.portal.kernel.template.TemplateContextContributor;

import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;

@Component(
  immediate = true,
  property = "type=" + TemplateContextContributor.TYPE_GLOBAL,
 service = TemplateContextContributor.class
)
public class BladeTemplateContextContributor
  implements TemplateContextContributor {

/**
 * Injects a new string variable into the map of provided variables. The map
 * is made available to non-JSP templates (FreeMarker, Velocity, etc.) that
 * do not have access to the contextual objects native to the platform, like
 * the request and session.
 *
 * <p>
 * The <code>sample_text</code> variable can be used in any theme file.
 * For example, you could add it to the <code>portal_normal.ftl</code> file
 * in your theme as <code>${sample_text}</code>.
 * </p>
 *
 * @param contextObjects the variables available in the context
 * @param httpServletRequest the HTTP servlet request
 */
@Override
public void prepare(
    Map<String, Object> contextObjects,
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {

    contextObjects.put("sample_text", "This is some sample text");
    }
 }
```

---

after you package and deploy to liferay tomcat you will be able to access the values from freemarker, velocity , theme

In freemarker like this : ${sample_text}

In addition you can see the scope here is GLOBAL
property = "type=" + TemplateContextContributor.TYPE_GLOBAL

you can change it to theme if you would like to get the values in the themes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).